# How to prevent/"reverse" displacement from a collision?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

[image: Gif of the problem]

- In my game I can throw a hammer. The hammer moves based on physics in Unity.
- The hammer destroys the first object it touches. **I want it to continue moving as though it didn't touch anything when this happens.**
- To try and achieve this, I made it destroy objects **using a separate, larger trigger collider**, intending to destroy the object before the physical collision occurs.
- However, when **moving at very high speeds** (as in the GIF), **both colliders hit at once**, so the hammer moves and the object deletes.

How can I prevent the hammer from moving when/before the trigger occurs, or (I suppose more realistically) "reverse" the movement such that there's no perceptible collision?

I tried using the impulses from each of the contacts in the collision to apply forces in reverse, but didn't really understand what I was doing and ultimately failed.

NOTE: I cannot simply disable the physics collider, because it doesn't destroy everything.

Comment: Have you considered using physics layers and the collision matrix, so that the non-trigger collider will only collide with things the hammer can't destroy?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you’re handling either OnTriggerEnter or OnCollisionEnter. Try capturing RigidBody.velocity in there, then set a flag to set the RigidBody.velocity to the captured Vector3 in the next FixedUpdate.